# create-react-app (Found incompatible module)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have this problem on `create-react-app`

my `node version 10.16.3`

my `npm version 6.9.0`

```
npx create-react-app mac
```

Creating a new React app in `/home/brian/Documentos/mac/mac`.

> warning You are using Node "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
>   Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
>   Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
>
> yarn add v1.17.3
>   warning You are using Node "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
>   [1/4] Resolving packages...
>   [2/4] Fetching packages...
>   error @babel/core@7.5.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=6.9.0". Got "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f"
>   error Found incompatible module.
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
>
> Aborting installation.
>
> yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /home/brian/Documentos/mac/mac has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json
>
> Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
>
> Deleting mac/ from /home/brian/Documentos/mac
>
> Done.

Answer (score 4):

```
create-react-app react-app --use-npm
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It appears the node version you're using isn't compatible. Can you try using node 10 or 12? I suggest using [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage the different node versions.

Many packages define an explicit node version in their `package.json`. For example, in [`@babel/core`](https://unpkg.com/@babel/core@7.6.0/package.json):

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=6.9.0"
},
```

It seems your node version: `13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f` isn't valud for these requirements.

You can [see the source](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/8deceab891bb2c7f082e81084643bec6bca77bfa/src/package-compatibility.js#L62-L96) in `yarn` that handles this.

You can [see here](https://codesandbox.io/s/semver-test-crwel) that it appears the `semver` package does not handle this:

```
import semver from "semver";

console.log(semver.satisfies("13.0.0", ">=6.9.0")); // true
console.log(semver.satisfies("13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f", ">=6.9.0")); // false
```